# How to insert table1 filed to another table2 with same table2.filed

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

MS SQL- 2014

I have table as temp (time, name) and Name (name)

In Name table we have data as (Ram, Shyam).

I want to insert data as Insert Into temp (time, name) Values (10:30, 'Ram') , (10:30, 'Shyam' );

But Want to automate to insert data on temp table as Insert should take time as current time and insert all the row from Name table.

Does it possible using SQL query?

Comment: Are you asking how to insert records into `Table2` containing values from `Table1`, or are you asking how to automatically insert a record into `Table2` with values from `Table1` when an `INSERT` is made to `Table1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert values from Name table as below

```
INSERT INTO temp (time, name) SELECT GETDATE(), Name from Name
```